# Rails Single Sign On and SAML For Multiple Organizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, saml

This is more about a suggestion question than a specific implementation question.

Currently for my Ruby on Rails project I'm using Devise to manage users. I also have a model `Account` such that each user belongs to an account and an account has many users. An account can be thought as an organization or company, or basically my a customer of mine.

I have many accounts (i.e. many customers). Now one of them uses my product together with many other web apps developed by themselves or other vendors. That customer(account) wishes to allow single sign on for my product and those other products from themselves or other vendors. I have implemented a solution using Devise and Devise_Saml_Authenticatable gems with Okta as the Identity Provider and it works for that one customer(account).

However, with that implementation, all users of all accounts must first be created on Okta and when they login, they all need to go through the single sign on process with Okta and this is not what I want. I want users of accounts that do not require SSO to just use the default sign on page and sign on without having to do anything with Okta.

My User model looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :recoverable, :timeoutable, :session_limitable, :saml_authenticatable
```

My routes involving devise and devise_saml_authenticatable is declared as:

`devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]` and the resulting routes are:

```
 new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                            devise/passwords#new
                       edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                           devise/passwords#edit
                            user_password PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#update
                                          PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#update
                                          POST     /users/password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#create
                 cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#cancel
                    new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                                 devise/registrations#new
                   edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#edit
                        user_registration PATCH    /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#update
                                          PUT      /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#update
                                          DELETE   /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                                          POST     /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#create
                         new_user_session GET      /users/saml/sign_in(.:format)                            devise/saml_sessions#new
                             user_session POST     /users/saml/auth(.:format)                               devise/saml_sessions#create
                     destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                devise/saml_sessions#destroy
                    metadata_user_session GET      /users/saml/metadata(.:format)                           devise/saml_sessions#metadata
                idp_sign_out_user_session GET|POST /users/saml/idp_sign_out(.:format)                       devise/saml_sessions#idp_sign_out
                                 new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)                                     users#new
                                edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                users#edit
                                     user PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#update
                                          PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#update
```

Note that I had to do `skip: [:sessions]` because otherwise I got error `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.`

My biggest question is:

Suppose I have an customer (customer A) that wants SSO on my app and other apps managed by that customer A only, and have an other customer (customer B) that wants SSO on my app and other apps managed by customer B only, and another customer C that does not want SSO and only wants the old Devise sign in methods; and also that customers do not share any user information in between (I think this requires customers A, B to provide their own identity providers). Is there a way to do it? Note that for customer C, my current devise sessions routes cannot work due to the conflict error above.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand your question, and what exactly you are trying to do. e.g. what is Otka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need two separate login flows. Usually sites will have a normal login form that also has a "Login with [insert idp here]" button. Click the button, head off to idp, login, get sent back to a specific saml endpoint that logs you in locally and away you go.

All of your users will see the saml login button, unless you give your saml customer a different login page for them to use, but there's really no problem having these buttons, they're everywhere now! Even stack lets you login with google.

Comment: Thanks @Matt! Right now I'm using Devise gem and devise-saml-authenticatable gem and Okta as my identity provider. However, I had to do `devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]` instead of just `devise_for :users`. With `devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]` the normal login page is gone and every login/logout will be handled by Identity provider. In other words, users who would like to use the normal devise login route will not be able to use the devise login route. I'm wondering if I am using the wrong gem for this and should go for something else?

Comment: @jl118 What did you end up doing here?